# gmaps.js Api doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

I want to add a googlemap to my html page using gmaps.js api. I put the gmaps.js file to same folder with my html page but when i try to load my html page nothing happens below is my code

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <title>TaxiPolis|@Web-taxi</title>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" scr="gmaps.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web_taxi_css.css"/>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="web_taxi_java.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**css:**

```
       @charset "utf-8";
      /* CSS Document */

     body{
          width:100%;
          height:100;
        }

    #map_canvas{
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         }
```

**javascript:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

          var map = new GMaps({
          div: '#map_canvas',
          lat: -12.043333,
          lng: -77.028333
         });
    });
```

So when I test it on Google Chrome and IE I get the Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: GMaps is not defined

Any ideas why this happening?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this not happen in FireFox? Does `gmaps.js` actually load? Is it in the place you've specified? Check the console network tab to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html has a typo:

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="gmaps.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gmaps.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even when you narrowed it down it still took me a couple of minutes to figure out what the difference was. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

The `GMaps` object does not exist. You have to use an object of the type `google.maps.Map` to load a map on your page.

This should be your javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {center: {lat:-12.04333, lng:-77.02833}});
});
```

A basic example can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld).